Display the same image in specific arrangements
I wish to display images in specific arrangements, much like these Blokus pieces

For example, here are some apples arranged in shape number 6.

I can individually code each one, for example here is the code that achieves shape 6:
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node[inner sep=0pt] at (2, 6) {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{apple}}; 
\node[inner sep=0pt] at (2, 4) {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{apple}}; 
\node[inner sep=0pt] at (0, 2) {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{apple}};
\node[inner sep=0pt] at (2, 2) {\includegraphics[width=.15\textwidth]{apple}}; \end{tikzpicture}

However I was hopeful that it might be possible to define a 4x4 grid, and then specify which positions I would like to place the apple in.
For example:
The grid might be

And then the apple diagram would be \GridImage{B, F, J, N, M}{apple}
Thanks so much,
Wendy

You can adapt the code of a plan partition as in this question  Correct the code of Jang Soo Kim's Plane partition example from "texample.net"

Here's one way to do this. I've used a property list to store the coordinates of the grid, and two key value parameters to adjust the sizes: one to set the x and y value of the grid itself, and the other the scale for the image.  If your images are uniform size, you can set these values initially using the \GridSetup command. The images themselves are inserted with the command \GridPlace. Rather than use the letters A-P to denote the grid positions, I've used a more readable a1-a4, b1-b4, etc. which makes visualizing positions much simpler.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn {grid} {
    grid.dim_set:N = \l_wendy_grid_dim,
    grid.initial:n = .75cm,
    scale.tl_set:N = \l_wendy_scale_tl,
    scale.initial:n = .15
}
\prop_new:N \l_wendy_grid_prop
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_wendy_grid_prop {
a1 = {(0,6)},
a2 = {(2,6)},
a3 = {(4,6)},
a4 = {(6,6)},
b1 = {(0,4)},
b2 = {(2,4)},
b3 = {(4,4)},
b4 = {(6,4)},
c1 = {(0,2)},
c2 = {(2,2)},
c3 = {(4,2)},
c4 = {(6,2)},
d1 = {(0,0)},
d2 = {(2,0)},
d3 = {(4,0)},
d4 = {(6,0)}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\GridSetup}{m}{
    \keys_set:nn {grid}{#1}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\GridPlace}{O{}mm}{
\group_begin:
\GridSetup{#1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=\l_wendy_grid_dim,y=\l_wendy_grid_dim]
    \clist_map_inline:nn {#2} {
        \prop_get:NnN \l_wendy_grid_prop {##1} \l_tmpa_tl
        {\node~at~\l_tmpa_tl~{\includegraphics[scale=\l_wendy_scale_tl]{#3}};}
        }
\end{tikzpicture}
\group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\GridPlace{b1,b2,b3,a2,c2}{cow}

\GridPlace[grid=.5cm,scale=.1]{a1,b1,c1,d1,d2}{cow}

\GridPlace[scale=.1]{a1,a2,a3,a4,b4}{cow}

\GridPlace[grid=.55cm,scale=.05]{a1,a2,b2,c2,d2}{cow}
\end{document}



This is perfect, thank you!

This is an adaption of Alan's answer which avoids the use of tikz and adds options to show the grid and set the grid size. The maximum grid size is 4 by 4, because the property list holding the translations for a1 etc. only defines 4 rows and 4 columns. However, this could obviously be extended if required.
By default, the grid is not shown but the full grid is set in terms of space. By restricting the number of columns and/or rows, this space is reduced. I've included show grid for the first of Alan's examples and a variant to demonstrate these options.
Note that the setup is a little different, possibly. I'm not sure if my rows and columns run the same way. Moreover, for Alan's setup, you needed to specify half of the grid dimension you wanted, whereas you should specify the actual value here. So, in Alan's examples, I've doubled the grid dimensions to compensate.

\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/718972/ addaswyd o ateb Alan Munn: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/718956/ addaswyd o gwestiwn Wendy Taylor: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/718908/
\usepackage{graphicx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { wendy } {
    grid.dim_set:N = \l_wendy_grid_dim,
    grid.initial:n = 1.5cm,
    scale.tl_set:N = \l_wendy_scale_tl,
    scale.initial:n = .15,
    rows .int_set:N = \l_wendy_rows_int,
    rows .initial:n = 4,
    cols .int_set:N = \l_wendy_cols_int,
    cols .initial:n = 4,
    show ~ grid .bool_set:N = \l_wendy_show_bool,
    show ~ grid .initial:n = false,
    show ~ grid .default:n = true,
}
\box_new:N \l_wendy_grid_box
\prop_new:N \l_wendy_grid_prop
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \wendy_put:nn #1 #2 {
  \put #1 {#2}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \wendy_put:nn { V }
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_wendy_grid_prop {
  a1 = {(0,0)},
  a2 = {(0,1)},
  a3 = {(0,2)},
  a4 = {(0,3)},
  b1 = {(1,0)},
  b2 = {(1,1)},
  b3 = {(1,2)},
  b4 = {(1,3)},
  c1 = {(2,0)},
  c2 = {(2,1)},
  c3 = {(2,2)},
  c4 = {(2,3)},
  d1 = {(3,0)},
  d2 = {(3,1)},
  d3 = {(3,2)},
  d4 = {(3,3)}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\GridSetup}{m}{
  \keys_set:nn {wendy}{#1}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\GridPlace}{O{}mm}{
  \group_begin:
  \GridSetup{#1}
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_wendy_grid_box { \includegraphics[scale=\l_wendy_scale_tl] { #3 } }
  \setlength \unitlength {\l_wendy_grid_dim}
  \begin{picture}(\l_wendy_cols_int,\l_wendy_rows_int)(0,0)
    \clist_map_inline:nn {#2} {
      \prop_get:NnN \l_wendy_grid_prop {##1} \l_tmpa_tl
      \wendy_put:Vn \l_tmpa_tl {\box_use:N \l_wendy_grid_box}
    }
    \bool_if:NT \l_wendy_show_bool
    {
      \int_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_int \l_wendy_rows_int
      \int_set_eq:NN \l_tmpb_int \l_wendy_cols_int
      \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
      \int_incr:N \l_tmpb_int
      \multiput(0,0)(0,1){\l_tmpa_int} {\line(1,0){\l_wendy_cols_int}}
      \multiput(0,0)(1,0){\l_tmpb_int} {\line(0,1){\l_wendy_rows_int}}
    }
  \end{picture}
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\GridPlace[show grid]{b1,b2,b3,a2,c2}{cow}
\GridPlace[rows=3,cols=3,show grid]{b1,b2,b3,a2,c2}{cow}

\GridPlace[grid=1cm,scale=.1,rows=4,cols=2]{a1,b1,c1,d1,d2}{cow}

\GridPlace[scale=.1,rows=2,cols=4]{a1,a2,a3,a4,b4}{cow}

\GridPlace[grid=1.1cm,scale=.05,rows=4,cols=2]{a1,a2,b2,c2,d2}{cow}
\end{document}


Thanks for your response, also very neat!

@WendyTaylor Believe it or not, this version is lighter weight. But if you're using tikz anyway, that's no advantage ;).

I am using a lot of tikz :)
